# how to solve websocket.onclose error in thirdweb?

Tags: typescript, next.js, web3-react, thirdweb

I am new to next.js,I a, developing a website based on web3
so I have to use thirdweb.

First I ran this command to add thirdweb to my project :

```
yarn add @thirdweb-dev/react @thirdweb-dev/sdk ethers
```

then I changed the app.tsx to these codes :

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

import { ChainId, ThirdwebProvider } from "@thirdweb-dev/react"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (

<ThirdwebProvider desiredChainId={ChainId.Rinkeby}>

  <Component {...pageProps} />

</ThirdwebProvider>
  )

}

export default MyApp
```

finally it errors:

> Call Stack
> webSocket.onclose
> node_modules@coinbase\wallet-sdk\dist\connection\RxWebSocket.js (50:0)

could you help me with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure exactly the issue based on this post alone, but you can get started with the recommended setup for thirdweb + Next.js with the CLI:

```bash
npx thirdweb create --app --next
```

I think your issue might be related to the versions of the SDK you're using - could you provide those here for us?